# Problem to get the data out of GNU Radio Companion (3.7.11)

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

First, I have to say that I'm a noobie posting at this site.

I have written this post because I'm trying to detect signals in the 2.4GHz band. For that, I'm using GNU Radio Companion with this result that worked for me:

[image: IMG: Simple program that detect the 2.4GHz frequency band]

But I want to get the information to a python script to work with it.

I was looking for something that can help me to make that possible and I found this tutorial: http://recolog.blogspot.com/2015/08/processing-data-out-of-gnuradio.html

I tried to replicated it but I have this problem:

[image: IMG: Tutorial Flow graph with error]

[image: IMG: Error description]

I have been searching for hours and I found this problem is caused by the version of the GNU Radio (in my case, 3.7.11), but I can't install a previous version because it cause troubles between other packages that I need.

So the question is, How can I replicate the tutorial in my current version?

Comment: That pad is a pad for a hierarchical block; I'm not sure what you intended the Pad Sink to do?

Comment: In the tutorial is used to get the data and use them in a python script to work with, do you know another way to extract the data and use them in a python script?

Comment: can you link to that tutorial? Sounds wrong.

Comment: This is the tutorial: http://recolog.blogspot.com/2015/08/processing-data-out-of-gnuradio.html

Comment: I don't know what they're doing, but a pad sink there doesn't make any sense. So, use the [official GNU Radio tutorials](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org). Also don't use WX GUI but QT GUI – we've deprecated WX *a long time ago*, and we've removed it completely from the upcoming release.

Comment: By the way, a better question would be "I want to do {explain} in python with data coming from GNU Radio, specifically {describe what you want GNU Radio to do}. How can I do that?" -- I'm pretty sure that as a GNU Radio developer, I wouldn't have taken an approach similar to that blog article you've linked to, at all. (Also, that blog article is generally kind of dated.)

Answer (score 1):

**the red tipped arrow indicate that the data format on either ends (output of a block to input of a block) are incompatible for connection.**

***Possible solution***

The easiest method is to use a <kbd>file sink</kbd>  block in gnuradio-companion

The <kbd>file sink</kbd>  block allows you to write into any format.

You can later take this file and analyse for detecting

Comment: I will try this solution later. I will say how it has gone.

Answer (score 0):

take new pad sink block, change properties( lable=output, inputtype=message, vectorlength=2048 ) in the pad block without connecting to the message sink, after changing it connect the wire to message sink.

then your grc does not show any error.